# Custom plugin module does not appear while creating new project in WebStorm

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, plugins, webstorm

I am developing a plugin for JetBrains WebStorm. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE for development.

My problem is: when I debug my plugin from IDEA, it works as expected. I can see my custom module option on the menu when creating a new project. But when I build my plugin and upload the .jar in WebStorm, I can't see that option on the menu. I also tried "remote debugging" in IDEA to WebStorm but failed to run.

I added this line to my `plugin.xml` for enabling my plugin for all platforms:

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
```

Actually I know this works because if I try to run one of my plugin's action using shortcuts, it's working. But as I've said my main problem is module option does not appear on the "new project" menu.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Does idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") in WebStorm contain any warning/error messages?

Comment: @y.bedrov it just says that my custom plugin loaded successfully. other messages and errors are not about this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out that we can not use components like "module builder" while developing a custom plugin for WebStorm because it won't be called while creating a project on WebStorm unlike IDEA.

> Small IDEs don't use module types during project generation (they use default one, e.g. WebModuleType for WebStorm), so the module builder just won't be called

says Dennis Ushakov.

You can see his full answer from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000738670-custom-plugin-module-does-not-appear-while-creating-new-project-in-WebStorm)

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed how to enable the plugin for all products, I made exactly the same change in one of my plugins, here:

https://github.com/Steve-Murphy/autoscroll-plugin/blob/master/META-INF/plugin.xml

I can only think that perhaps the plugin isn't updating properly - rebuild it, remove it completely from the IDE (uninstall and check it's gone from plugins/) and install it again.

Failing that, try installing "Autoscroll Save" plugin - if it doesnt install on WebStorm then there is something weird happening.